# Charles proxy freeze

Tags: proxy, freeze, charles-proxy

After a windows update my Charles proxy freeze after 10min of usage. This never happened before, i tried reinstalling windows, updating charles, update drivers but the problem persist. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add more detail - this question can't be answered if you don't provide more data...

Comment: I am testing my website by sending a lot of request with Charles using repeat advanced tool. After 10min Charles just freeze and i have to close it.

Comment: This doesn't help. Please add more information to your question - e.g. proxy config, how you test etc...

Comment: I use default Charles settings, i use a dynamic port, the address is my localhost, i record web traffic with charles then i repeat it a lot of times using repeat advanced tool. A new session is open with the results. After 10min Charles just freeze. Lets say that one day Charles was working just fine then a windows update came and the next day Charles freeze after 10min. Can the new updates for windows 10 be the problem? I tried reinstall the windows but i downloaded the last version which contains the latest updates i quess and that could cause the problem? Sorry for my English

Comment: Start Charles Proxy from the command line and make it crash (or wait till it does). 
You may find some useful information there.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like Charles is running out of memory, there is information about this on their website; https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ "Charles runs out of memory", where clearing the session could help or increasing the heap size.

Comment: i was thinking about that too but i made a bot that automatically clean the session every minute. In the past the bot was cleaning the session every 10 min and Charles was running just fine